# Position tippy tooltip next to button in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tippyjs

I would like to add a tooltip to a button using [tippy 1.0.0](https://tippy.john-coene.com/).

The tooltip always appears in the middle of the screen and not close to the text as expected.

I tried to specifiy the position arguments, but had no success. I was able to position the tooltips correctly in tippy version 0.1.0.

How can I position the tooltip close to the text?

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
      tippy(
        element = p("Test"),
        content = "Tooltip"
      )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: I also posted this problem under an issue in the tippy github repo https://github.com/JohnCoene/tippy/issues/18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your tags are displayed as `block` in CSS. Even though the element only shows a small portion of the total width, but it is still occupying the full width of the parent node by default. This is how CSS display works. `tippy` works on the whole occupied width, not what you see with your eyes. Use your `p` tag for example to inspect:

[image]

See the blue shade that takes the entire row? `tippy` is displayed at the center of the shade.

We can change the `display` to another to force the tooltip to be positioned around `p`, like `inline-block`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tippy(
            element = p(
                "Test", 
                style = "display: inline-block"
            ),
            content = "Tooltip"
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image]

When you inspect, the size is what we want.

[image]

However (there is always a however), this may mess up your UI display. e.g., we want a button in the second line, but here is what you will see

[image]

```r
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tippy(
            element = p(
                "Test", 
                style = "display: inline-block"
            ),
            content = "Tooltip"
        ),
        tags$button("Test2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

To fix, you can add a wrapper outside your tooltip tag with `block` display,

```r
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        div(style = "display: block", 
            tippy(
                element = p(
                    "Test", 
                    style = "display: inline-block"
                ),
                content = "Tooltip"
            )
        ),
        tags$button("Test2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image]

Or I'd prefer an easier way:

```r
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        p(tippy(element = tags$span("Test" ), content = "Tooltip")),
        tags$button("Test2")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Please read more about CSS display: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp